# Ruby - net/http - following redirects

Tags: ruby, http-headers, httpclient, net-http

I've got a URL and I'm using HTTP GET to pass a query along to a page.  What happens with the most recent flavor (in `net/http`) is that the script doesn't go beyond the 302 response.  I've tried several different solutions; HTTPClient, net/http, Rest-Client, Patron...

I need a way to continue to the final page in order to validate an attribute tag on that pages html.  The redirection is due to a mobile user agent hitting a page that redirects to a mobile view, hence the mobile user agent in the header.  Here is my code as it is today:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

class Check_Get_Page

    def more_http
        url = URI.parse('my_url')
        req, data = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path, {
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5'
        })
        res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
        http.request(req)
            }
        cookie = res.response['set-cookie']
        puts 'Body = ' + res.body
        puts 'Message = ' + res.message
        puts 'Code = ' + res.code
        puts "Cookie \n" + cookie
    end

end

m = Check_Get_Page.new
m.more_http
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I used [final_redirect_url](https://rubygems.org/gems/final_redirect_url) gem to get the final url after multiple redirections.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To follow redirects, you can do something like this ([taken from ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html))

**Following Redirection**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0

  url = URI.parse(uri_str)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path, { 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (etc...)' })
  response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, use_ssl: true) { |http| http.request(req) }
  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess     then response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then fetch(response['location'], limit - 1)
  else
    response.error!
  end
end

print fetch('http://www.ruby-lang.org/')
```

Comment: Any clue as to how to add a user-agent to the header?  
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri_str.encode),{'User-Agent' => ua})

I tried that and it doesn't seem to work.  I get the following error:
c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:581:in `initialize': can't convert URI::HTTP into String (TypeError)

Comment: This does NOT work for a link that is redirected to itself but adding a back-slash, for example, `fetch('http://epn.dk/okonomi2/dk/ECE5373277/chefoekonom-corydon-skyder-langt-over-mal')`, the first iteration, it generates `#<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>`, then exception...

Comment: This does not work when the `response['Location']` is a relative path, e.g.: '/inbox'.  In such a case, the original uri's path needs to be set, e.g.: `url.path = response['Location']`.

Comment: where you define ua variable?

Comment: @MattHuggins According to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), the location header should always be an absolute URI, never a relative path. Where are you seeing relative paths?

Comment: @DavidMoles I don't know, that was 2 years ago.  But it happened!

Comment: @DavidMoles -- For instance, `http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=9999` -- curl shows 302 redirect with `Location: /` header, and the above code pattern chokes without @MattHuggins advice. Or rather, with slight tweak -- craft new `new_uri = URI.parse(response['Location'])` then `if new_uri.relative?` set `new_uri.scheme = uri.scheme' and 'new_uri.host = uri.host` -- otherwise if you try to update the original path, then any query or fragment section will still remain from the original uri.

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Following+Redirection

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn, I believe port also need to be updated from old uri.

Comment: @MattHuggins, @DreadPirateShawn: Rather than copying specific URI attributes, Use `URI.join(old_uri, new_location)`. That will keep any attributes unspecified in `new_location` from the old URI, but use the new scheme or hostname if they are provided.

Answer (score 11):

Given a URL that redirects

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpbin.org%2Fredirect-to%3Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.org'
```

A. `Net::HTTP`

```
begin
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
  url = response['location']
end while response.is_a?(Net::HTTPRedirection)
```

Make sure that you handle the case when there are too many redirects.

B. `OpenURI`

```
open(url).read
```

`OpenURI::OpenRead#open` follows redirects by default, but it doesn't limit the number of redirects.

Comment: open-uri is vulnerable to remote code execution attacks

Answer (score 6):

I wrote another class for this based on examples given here, thank you very much everybody. I added cookies, parameters and exceptions and finally got what I need: https://gist.github.com/sekrett/7dd4177d6c87cf8265cd

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

class UrlResolver
  def self.resolve(uri_str, agent = 'curl/7.43.0', max_attempts = 10, timeout = 10)
    attempts = 0
    cookie = nil

    until attempts >= max_attempts
      attempts += 1

      url = URI.parse(uri_str)
      http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
      http.open_timeout = timeout
      http.read_timeout = timeout
      path = url.path
      path = '/' if path == ''
      path += '?' + url.query unless url.query.nil?

      params = { 'User-Agent' => agent, 'Accept' => '*/*' }
      params['Cookie'] = cookie unless cookie.nil?
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path, params)

      if url.instance_of?(URI::HTTPS)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      end
      response = http.request(request)

      case response
        when Net::HTTPSuccess then
          break
        when Net::HTTPRedirection then
          location = response['Location']
          cookie = response['Set-Cookie']
          new_uri = URI.parse(location)
          uri_str = if new_uri.relative?
                      url + location
                    else
                      new_uri.to_s
                    end
        else
          raise 'Unexpected response: ' + response.inspect
      end

    end
    raise 'Too many http redirects' if attempts == max_attempts

    uri_str
    # response.body
  end
end

puts UrlResolver.resolve('http://www.ruby-lang.org')
```

Comment: Thanks for this code snippet!  I think you may want to close the http connections (`finish`) though so they don't leak.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Definitely the best solution for me thus far. I could easily work with the page with `html_to_parse = Nokogiri::HTML(UrlResolver.resolve('http://www.ruby-lang.org'))` afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure 100%, but in Ruby I think every object get destroyed automatically when get out of scope of def function.

Comment: You can also use `url.request_uri` instead of manually constructing `path`, it includes the query params.

Comment: @gmcnaughton, nice. Can you send me a pull request on Github?

Answer (score 3):

The reference that worked for me is here: http://shadow-file.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/handling-http-redirection-in-ruby.html

Compared to most examples (including the accepted answer here), it's more robust as it handles  URLs which are just a domain (http://example.com - needs to add a /), handles SSL specifically, and also relative URLs.

Of course you would be better off using a library like RESTClient in most cases, but sometimes the low-level detail is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use curb-fu gem here https://github.com/gdi/curb-fu the only thing is some extra code to make it follow redirect. I've used the following before. Hope it helps.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb-fu'

module CurbFu
  class Request
    module Base
      def new_meth(url_params, query_params = {})
        curb = old_meth url_params, query_params
        curb.follow_location = true
        curb
      end

      alias :old_meth :build
      alias :build :new_meth
    end
  end
end

#this should follow the redirect because we instruct
#Curb.follow_location = true
print CurbFu.get('http://<your path>/').body
```

Comment: I've had complications in getting curb-fu to work on my Windows machine using Ruby 1.9.1p430... I can get it to work on my Mac but since this is something I have to run on a Windows server I need curb-fu to complete installation.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to care about the details at each redirection, you can use the library [Mechanize](https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize)

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
begin
    response = @agent.get(url)
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    // response codes other than 200, 301, or 302
rescue Timeout::Error
rescue Mechanize::RedirectLimitReachedError
rescue StandardError
end
```

It will return the destination page.
Or you can turn off redirection by this :

```
agent.redirect_ok = false
```

Or you can optionally change some settings at the request

```
agent.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```