# Ruby open-uri redirect forbidden

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I have this simple html parser(for learning purposes) that I have been working on.:

```
require 'open-uri'
puts "Enter URL to parse HTML: "
url = gets.chomp
puts "Enter tag to parse from: "
tag = gets.chomp
response = open(url).read
title1 = response.index(tag)
title2 = response.index(tag.insert(1,'/')) -1
result = response[(title1 + tag.length - 1)..title2]
print result
```

and when I input `http://twitter.com`, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: `open_loop': redirection forbidden: http://twitter.com -> https://twitter.com/ (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/htmlparse.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Any advise or help? Im new to Ruby and I am aware of other html parsing modules, but Im doing this to learn Ruby basics. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that's happening because twitter uses `https`.  FWIW - you may want to hit a site like `http://www.example.org` instead of twitter if you're just looking to learn and poke around.

Comment: I know `http://` website work, but I thought open-uri automatically redirects to https, `https://twitter.com` works, but http doesnt, are there any solutions?

Comment: My advice: download that file to some server you control (github, bintray) so it can avoid redirects (sorry had to pipe in)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look at the [open_uri_redirections](https://github.com/open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections) gem.

It patches Ruby's OpenURI to allow redirections from HTTP to HTTPS or the other way around.

Answer (score 21):

You can also catch the exception and then try it again with 'https' url.

```
url = "http://classic.ona.io/api/v1/files/3538545?filename=gringgo/attachments/1485229166168.jpg"

uri = URI.parse(url)
tries = 3

begin
  uri.open(redirect: false)
rescue OpenURI::HTTPRedirect => redirect
  uri = redirect.uri # assigned from the "Location" response header
  retry if (tries -= 1) > 0
  raise
end
```

Source: https://twin.github.io/improving-open-uri/

Comment: Much more elegant than adding another dependency to handle this.

Comment: Brilliant! A sterling snippet, just what I needed.

Comment: superb answer - just a note - using this approach the redirect: false is required in the open() call in order for the open to throw the OpenURI::HTTPRedirect exception type

Answer (score 8):

Ruby 2.4 fixed upgrade redirects (from http -> https) in `open-uri`, so now:

```
RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.4.2"

require 'open-uri'
=> true

open('http://twitter.com')
=> #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri20170926-24254-1kflwxq>
```

Source: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/03/02/open-uri-in-ruby-2-4-allows-http-to-https-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

Just override in your source file the method *redirectable?* from *open-uri* that checks if redirect is allowed or not and return always true to allow redirect for all cases.

```
require 'open-uri'

def OpenURI.redirectable?(uri1, uri2)
  return true
end

url = "http://someurl.jpg"

URI.open(url)
```