# EU Central Bank Gem redirection forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

Currently I am receiving an error message from eu central bank gem on rails as;

```
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629896+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error ID: 79f8e4f3
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629903+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error.ZqeFNI
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629905+00:00 app[web.1]:   Message from application: redirection forbidden: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml -> https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml (RuntimeError)
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629907+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629908+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:150:in `open_uri'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629912+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:716:in `open'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629916+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629919+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eu_central_bank-0.5.0/lib/eu_central_bank.rb:87:in `doc'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629941+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eu_central_bank-0.5.0/lib/eu_central_bank.rb:20:in `update_rates'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.629976+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/initializers/money.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630007+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630038+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630069+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630099+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630128+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630158+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630205+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630344+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630376+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630409+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630438+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630467+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2018-09-06T18:26:20.630497+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
```

I think there is a problem with the gem or the xml folder. But it happened suddenly. The application is closed right now on rails. Can not change the link from http to https

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, you are facing the same problem as this one:

[Ruby open-uri redirect forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407938/ruby-open-uri-redirect-forbidden)

It's caused because the EU central bank forced a redirection to `https` but `openuri` library is not allowing this and that's why you get this error: `redirection forbidden`.

There is a gem called `open_uri_redirections` that will patch the `openuri` to allow redirections.

https://github.com/open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections

All you need to do is to:

- include this gem in your `Gemfile`.
- `$ bundle install` to install the newly added gem.
- `require 'open_uri_redirections'`

This should fix your issue temporarily.

---

Another fix (recommended) is to monkey patch `eu_central_bank` gem to override

`ECB_RATES_URL`  at `eu_central_bank/lib/eu_central_bank.rb:20`

`ECB_90_DAY_URL`  at `eu_central_bank/lib/eu_central_bank.rb:21`

constants with `https` instead of `http`.

as follows (put this code to `config/initializers/patch_eu_central_bank.rb`):

```
require 'eu_central_bank'
class EuCentralBank
  ECB_RATES_URL = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'.freeze
  ECB_90_DAY_URL = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml'.freeze
end
```

You might see some warnings like:

`warning: already initialized constant EuCentralBank::ECB_RATES_URL`.

You can live with it till the PR merged at the `EuCentralBank` gem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Some people already suggested this, and I am trying to get it as `gem 'eu_central_bank', github: 'RubyMoney/eu_central_bank', ref: 'e7410a5c8cbb8f12e47da6ab0bc1f1246049bd52'` But this time it gives error; `fatal: Could not parse object 'e7410a5c8cbb8f12e47da6ab0bc1f1246049bd52'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard e7410a5c8cbb8f12e47da6ab0bc1f1246049bd52 in directory /Users/jack/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/bundler/gems/eu_central_bank-e7410a5c8cbb has failed.`

Comment: For the first solution, where shall I add `require 'open_uri_redirections'`?

Comment: in `config/initializers/patch_open_uri.rb`

Comment: I don't know why you are getting this error from your `Gemfile` but you can also monkey patch the URL to `https` yourself temporarily. I'll update my code to show how to do this

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try this:
`gem 'eu_central_bank', github: 'Etison/eu_central_bank', branch: 'use_https' `

Comment: This gave the same error. But I used your recommended solution and I will wait for the merge. Thank you again!