# Ruby - Send GET request with headers

Tags: ruby, http, http-headers

I am trying to use ruby with a website's api. The instructions are to send a GET request with a header. These are the instructions from the website and the example php code they give. I am to calculate a HMAC hash and include it under an `apisign` header.

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

I am simply using an .rb file with ruby installed on windows from command prompt. I am using net/http in the ruby file. How can I send a GET request with a header and print the response?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using `net/http` as suggested by the question.

References:

- `Net::HTTP` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html
- `Net::HTTP::get` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get
- **Setting headers**: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers
- `Net::HTTP::Get` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Get.html
- `Net::HTTPGenericRequest` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html and `Net::HTTPHeader` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html (for methods that you can call on `Net::HTTP::Get`)

So, for example:

```
require 'net/http'    

uri = URI("http://www.ruby-lang.org")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['some_header'] = "some_val"

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') { |http|
  http.request(req)
}

puts res.body # <!DOCTYPE html> ... </html> => nil
```

Note: if your `res`ponse has *HTTP result state 301 (Moved permanently)*, see [Ruby Net::HTTP - following 301 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210232/ruby-nethttp-following-301-redirects)

Comment: if I use `URI("https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent")` then the program doesn't work, with the error `end of file reached (EOFError)`. I think it is due to the `https` in the URL. Can the program work for any URL?

Comment: I think I found the answer: it is to change the `Net::HTTP.start` line to `Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,   
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https')`

Comment: @nonopoloarity How do you get the response body out of that?

Answer (score 18):

Install [`httparty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem, it makes requests way easier, then in your script

```
require 'httparty'

url = 'http://someexample.com'
headers = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

response = HTTParty.get(url, headers: headers)
puts response.body
```

then run your `.rb` file..

Comment: I myself prefer RestClient, but this is a popular one as well. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev any specific reason or just a personal preference?

Comment: In my mind, httparty is for those weird embedding scenarios. Where you include httparty module in your model or service and suddenly it can do remote calls. But yes, it can also clearly work standalone. I prefer restclient, because it doesn't offer me the choice. :)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 9):

As of Ruby 3.0, [`Net::HTTP.get_response`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response) supports an optional hash for headers:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('http://www.example.com/index.html'), { 'Accept' => 'text/html' })
```

Unfortunately this does not work for Ruby 2 (up to 2.7).