# how to store json to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

have URl want to store json data to database automatically

site provide this code but use Java

```
HttpResponse response = Unirest.get("https://xproject.restdb.io/rest/data")
  .header("x-apikey", "42ba8a6dc7532aa8319a58310281665e394e4")
  .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .asString();
```

This Example of json

[image]

model called **speed** contain `speed` & id
need save `gps_speed_kph = speed` & `id_watch ==_id`

Comment: To replicate what that code is doing, go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839503/ruby-send-get-request-with-headers

Comment: I read this link but not have any change ?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you have to specify the `db column` data type as `hash in` your `model` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694432/using-rails-serialize-to-save-hash-to-database).

Then you have to save your `json` as hash in your db `(json to hash )`:

```
require 'json'
value = '{"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}'
myhash = JSON.parse(value)
Model.create(hash_column_name: myhash)
```

and for converting you can do this `(hash to json)`:

```
@myhash = Model.find(1).hash_column_name
json_data = @myhash.to_json
```

Comment: but i not want to save hash ?i want save value  `id_watch = _id` save value only in column

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSONB column. This may help you to update the single are the group of data based on the key in the column.

Ref:

1) http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb

2) https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks this link is useful but how can get data from request and pass it

Comment: In above question, you show this is from external API call for that refer Net::HTTP[https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html] methods. Then parse the response and store into the database.

Comment: I can't get of data from url ?

Comment: Check first whether your requesting URL giving the data or not. For example, following URL will give the JSON result https://obscure-dawn-93833.herokuapp.com/api/appointments

Comment: Thanks @Gokul p id don't know write any things  explain what write ?