# Ruby putting token key in requests

Tags: ruby, api, noaa

I dont know how to put my key into my requests so they are sent back as

```
{"status"=>"400", "message"=>"Token parameter is required."}
```

This is the code I have been using

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

token = 'YiwwVvywLngtPT***************'
url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations?locationid=FIPS:23&limit=5&sortfield=mindate'
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
response.authorization = token
puts JSON.parse(response)
```

I have tried a couple different things I've found on the internet but all of them just give errors for

```
undefined method `methodname' for #<String:0x00007fd97519abd0>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2) (based on the URL you referenced), you need to provide the token in a header named `token`.

So, you should probably try some variation of the below (code untested):

```
token = 'YiwwVvywLngtPT***************'
url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations?locationid=FIPS:23&limit=5&sortfield=mindate'
uri = URI(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request['token'] = token
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

More information about `Net:HTTP` headers can be found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839503/ruby-send-get-request-with-headers).

---

As a side note, if you are not locked on using `Net::HTTP`, consider switching to a friendlier HTTP client, perhaps [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). Then, the complete code looks like this:

```
require 'httparty'

token = 'YiwwVvywLngtPT***************'
url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations?locationid=FIPS:23&limit=5&sortfield=mindate'
response = HTTParty.get url, headers: { token: token }

puts response.body
```