# I don't know how to set the access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce, httprequest, rest

Currently I am using Salesforce's rest api so that I can create and update objects in Salesforce.

By using curl command, I could find out that I can create and update the objects in salesforce as I wanted them to be.

Now I want to create a method that can do the same as I did with curl command. But it seems like I need to do something in order for the authorization as I read the error below.

```
#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized:0x000055a3702171e0>%
```

what I want to do is something like this.

1, I want to create the objects in salesforce.

2, to update objects I need Account obejcts.

3, so I want to create a method that extracts all Account objects from salesforce.

4, in a method I need to send Http request with access_token.

5, but I don't know how to set the access_token.

this is the curl command I tried for authentication and to get Account objects

OAuth

```
curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_id=3MasubgboasbboUIUBOBOUBOUBOJBUTFHBLKJHIU1rMmmDExvMtiR" \
  -d "client_secret=D33ASDFAS82C0EASDFAS48E8F1C21ASFASW6EF21C4D7AASDF4EB5EF3" \
  -d "username=MYNAME@COMPANY.co.jp.instance" -d "password=yatta-"
get Account curl "https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account" -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D1s0023202345234pwb!AQQasdgas3eOlKbprFFRMT_SLFp.Pwt5Q07AI0uHasdgasdxmasdgas2nLiaZ.baVoLZvVVaQK"
```

get Account

```
curl "https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account" -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D1s0023202345234pwb\!AQQasdgas3eOlKbprFFRMT_SLFp.Pwt5Q07AI0uHasdgasdxmasdgas2nLiaZ.baVoLZvVVaQK"
```

the code I tried is something like this.

```
  def get_salesforce_company_list
    #　hit api and get company list
    access_token = auth
    uri = URI.parse("https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account")
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request["Authorization"] = "Bearer" + access_token

    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    print response
  end

  def auth
    uri = URI.parse("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token")
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    request.set_form_data(
      "client_id" => "jnas;jdbojasn;djlnfalsjbdbkjbljasdasknl",
      "client_secret" => "asjbdabHVIVHBJNFLNLKNJDNSjbljsg",
      "grant_type" => "password",
      "password" => "yatta-",
      "username" => "Myname@COMPANY.co.jp.INSTANCE",
    )

    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    auth_info = JSON.parse(response.body)
    auth_info["access_token"]
  end
```

If anyone knows how to send http request or any ideas how to solve this, I would really appreciate.

EDITS

in the code above, "auth" method works fine and I can get the access_token correctly. the problem is that I can't set it to the "get_salesforce_company_list" method and use it as bearer token.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it manually with http requests? Maybe something ready-built like https://github.com/restforce/restforce will be simpler?

Anyway. Your curl example with `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` looks like you're using ["Username Password flow"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5).

On successful call you'll get back a JSON looking bit like this

```
{"id":"https://test.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
"issued_at":"1278448832702",
"instance_url":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/",
"signature":"0CmxinZir53Yex7nE0TD+zMpvIWYGb/bdJh6XfOH6EQ=",
"access_token":"00Dx0000000BV7z!AR8AQAxo9UfVkh8AlV0Gomt9Czx9LjHnSSpwBMmbRcgKFmxOtvxjTrKW19ye6PE3Ds1eQz3z8jr3W7_VbWmEu4Q8TVGSTHxs",
"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

Extract from here `instance_url` and `access_token`. All your next API calls should start with that instance (do not hardcode your sandbox's url) and include HTTP Header `Authorization Bearer {access_token_here}`

Comment: thank you so much for your comment. It seems you are right. I will check the gem later. In my code the "auth" method works fine and it returns the JSON like you mentions, and I want to "get_salesforce_company_list" method, I want to pass it as Authorization bearer {}. and I don't know how. I will try a bit though.

Comment: I updated my code please check it. now, I am working on using restforce version

Comment: Sorry man, my ruby knowledge is nonexistent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839503/ruby-send-get-request-with-headers ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my silly mistake, but the solution was something like the one below.

I needed to put the space after "Bearer"

request["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token

Thank you all for answering and sorry for my mistake.