# Salesforce API via postman error INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: postman, salesforce

I checked similar error post but couldn't resolve my issue.

I am able to run successfully https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/services/data from postman using generated access_token but not able to run https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/services/data/v56.0 or any version before that with the same access_token. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYgOz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcwP8.png)

Comment: get both the access token and the refresh token then use the refresh token to get a new access token.  this is how to prevent session time out errors

Answer (score 1):

No.

You don't need access token to use https://xxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data. You can view it in your browser without any fancy headers, even in incognito window. I don't need to be a British Airways / Heathrow employe to see https://baa.my.salesforce.com/services/data or even any generic https://eu32.my.salesforce.com/services/data.

This is the real start url. You know nothing about the org, you don't know which API versions it supports - here's a list. It can't be protected by login screen.

---

I don't think you did it right. Your second screenshot contains "lightning.force.com", I'd expect "my.salesforce.com". Maybe API v 56 is not in that org yet. But for sure the url is wrong, you're supposed to use `instance_url` from successful login response. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190644/313628 and screenshot in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873644/313628. You can't take only the session id (`access_token`)

And yes, sessions expire, anything between 15 min and 12h. What you can do next depends on how you got this access_token (some flows like "username password flow" don't generate refresh_token). Log in again or use refresh token to get new session id.

Comment: Thank you very much pointing me to the right direction. I was using url that I was using to get access_token for accessing resources under latest version. But after replacing url with the once I received in instance_url, it worked fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's very important to use what you get back in login response. If you hardcode production url and think it won't change - critical updates like "enhanced domains" will break your integration.