# Connect Salesforce to Postman

Tags: postman, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, postman-collection-runner

In the quick connection test, there's no response since I could not send any request through the "GET Limit" collection. I can't authenticate with Salesforce.

I tried installing the Postman Desktop Agent but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you forking the salesforce's recommended collection of API calls and following the instructions or did you hand-craft the requests? Have you seen my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74018275/313628 ? Can you post at least the raw http or curl form of your request and response (anonymised of course)

Comment: Yes, I'm forking the salesforce's recommended collection of API calls and followed the instructions.