# Following redirection and checking IP of website - Ruby

Tags: ruby, redirect, curl, net-http

I need to create simple script in Ruby. All I have to do is a check link like this: `www.mywebsite.com/redirect.php?=xxx` I must check where the link is  redirecting me and what exactly is a IP address of new location.

I've found solution for following redirects in Ruby here: [Ruby - net/http - following redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934185/ruby-net-http-following-redirects)

But the challenge is, that I do not know how to get current IP after redirect. It is possible to grab it somehow from response object?

Answer (score 0):

You edited your question and said you figured out the redirects. Once you have the URL you got redirected to, you can just use `IPSocket.getaddress` to find the IP:

```
>> IPSocket.getaddress 'www.google.com'
=> "209.85.148.104"
```