# Can't get page source code with ruby

Tags: ruby

The ruby code that should get the source code of a given website doesn't work.
It says that the site does not exist.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse("http://nice.com/careers?category=170")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response=http.request(request)
@data = response.body
```

It does work with other sites.

1. Why?
2. how to fix?

Comment: Just run this, and I got a redirection code. Are you sure it is saying site doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

I always like to check stuff using `curl` on the command line.

In this case it turns out a request to `http://nice.com/careers?category=170` gives you a `HTTP 301` redirect to the same domain but with `www.`:

```
curl -I "http://nice.com/careers?category=170"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 20:50:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.nice.com/careers?category=170
```

So update your code to to use the `www.nice.com` domain.

Also, you can implement logic to follow redirects, like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934503/25398