# How to solve HTTP Temporary Redirect error in using 'net/http' in ruby?

Tags: ruby, curl, http-headers, net-http

This following code continuously gives me `#<Net::HTTPTemporaryRedirect:0x00000001e8cc58>` error. I tried to look at [Ruby - net/http - following redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934185/ruby-net-http-following-redirects), but of no use.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
uri = URI.parse("https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/shahsaurabh0605%2FRuby-Docker/requests")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
output = `travis token --org`
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
request["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
request["Accept"] = 'application/json'
request["Travis-API-Version"] = '3'
request["Authorization"] = 'token '+output
request.body = {'request' => {'branch' => 'master'}}.to_json
response = https.request(request)
puts response
```

PS: If I remove the output variable and just paste the command line output in `request["Authorization"]` I get a success. Strange?

Comment: Why don't you output the result of your backticks:  `p output`, and compare that to the terminal output of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked where it redirects, and which other headers it returns?

Is it possible, that `travis token --org` includes a newline that you have to strip?

If that doesn't solve it, could you paste the response.inspect ?