# Only OpenURI succeeds at Reddit API request

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http, open-uri

I’m making requests to the Reddit API. First, I set a subreddit top URL:

```rb
reddit_url = URI.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/pixelart/top.json')
```

All of these correctly get the contents:

```rb
Net::HTTP.get(reddit_url, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')

Open3.capture2('/usr/bin/curl', '--user-agent', 'My agent', reddit_url.to_s)[0]

URI.open(reddit_url, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent').read
```

But then I try it with a URL for a specific post:

```rb
reddit_url = URI.parse('https://reddit.com/r/PixelArt/comments/lkaiqf/another_watercolour_pixelart_tree.json')
```

And both `Net::HTTP` and `Open3`/`curl` fail, getting only empty strings. `URI.open` continues to work, as does opening the URL in a web browser.

Why doesn’t the second request work with two of the solutions? And why does it work with `URI.open`, when that’s supposed to be “[an easy-to-use wrapper for Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)”? What does it do differently, and how to replicate it with `Net::HTTP` an `curl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your example, and focussing on Net::HTTP for simplicity, the first example doesn't work as written:

```
require 'net/http'
reddit_url = URI.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/pixelart/top.json')
Net::HTTP.get(reddit_url, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')
# => Type Error - no implicit conversion of URI::HTTPS into String
```

Instead I used this as my starting point:

```
require 'net/http'
reddit_url = URI.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/pixelart/top.json')
http = Net::HTTP.new(reddit_url.host, reddit_url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
result = http.get(reddit_url.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')
puts result
# => #<Net::HTTPOK:0x00007fc3ea8e7320>
puts result.body.size
# => 167,394
```

With that working we can try the second URL. Interestingly, I get different results depending on whether I re-use the initial connection or make a new one:

```
require 'net/http'
reddit_url = URI.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/pixelart/top.json')
reddit_url_two = URI.parse('https://reddit.com/r/PixelArt/comments/lkaiqf/another_watercolour_pixelart_tree.json')

http = Net::HTTP.new(reddit_url.host, reddit_url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
result = http.get(reddit_url.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')
puts result
# => #<Net::HTTPOK:0x00007f931a143390>
puts result.body.size
# => 174,615

http_two = Net::HTTP.new(reddit_url_two.host, reddit_url_two.port)
http_two.use_ssl = true
result_two = http_two.get(reddit_url_two.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')
puts result_two
# => #<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently:0x00007f931a148818>
puts result_two.body.size
# => 0

result_reusing_connection = http.get(reddit_url_two.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'My agent')
puts result_reusing_connection
# => #<Net::HTTPOK:0x00007f931a0fb3b0>
puts result_reusing_connection.body.size
# => 141,575
```

So I suspect you're getting a 301 redirect sometimes and that's causing the confusion. There's another [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934185/ruby-net-http-following-redirects) for how to follow redirects.

Comment: The first example works on Ruby 3.0 but doesn’t seem to work on older versions. That might explain the discrepancy on that one. You’re correct that the redirect was the problem (can’t believe I forgot to try `curl` with `--location`), though weirdly it seems to point to the same URL.

Comment: You're right, apparently I'm still on 2.7.2. I'm still not sure why reusing the first connection works... and I couldn't see a redirect happening when accessed from a browser... a few puzzling things there but glad you're on track now!