# How to figure out where a site redirects to using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I visit

```
https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+goodreads+quotes+A+Promised+Land+Barack+Obama&t=h_&ia=web
```

It ultimately redirects to

```
https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/86336100-a-promised-land
```

Using Ruby, is there a way to pass in the first duckduckgo page, but collect the final url that this redirects to?

I tried using

```
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI('https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+goodreads+quotes+A+Promised+Land+Barack+Obama&t=h_&ia=web'))
puts res['location']
```

but this only outputs the same duckduckgo link.

Comment: It's not the same duckduckgo link. The `location` header in the redirect uses the `duckduckgo.com` hostname rather than `www.duckduckgo.com`. When requesting this returned URL, the response contains some HTML/Javascript which performs the final redirect.

Comment: There are two additional redirects and each page contains a `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=...'>` element as well as a script tag. You could use Nokogiri to parse the page and get the URL. But be warned that its going to be a very brittle solution.

Comment: The [REFRESH header](https://codingshower.com/http-refresh-header-meta-refresh/) is an old non-standard header dating back to the days of Netscape which may cause the browser to redirect. Or not.

Comment: @max do you have advice on how that solution could/would work?

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks for the information, but I'm not sure what I should specifically add in Ruby to help me get a solution. do you have thoughts? thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not going to do your job for you. There are plenty of tutorials on how to parse HTML with Nokogiri as well as serveral questions which answer how to follow the initial redirect with Net::HTTP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934185/ruby-net-http-following-redirects

Comment: hi @max, I didn't mean to ask you to do all the work :). when I tried the upvoted answer and replaced the link above I'm trying to get to work, I still keep getting an error (400 "Bad Request")...so I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed. I'm not sure if the duckduckgo url above is actually redirecting or doing something else to get to the final result, maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

DuckDuckGo is sending you on multiple redirects, and some are through javascript. You'll need to either follow all these redirects manually with `Net::HTTP` and try to pull URLs out of the javascript, or use a different tool like [Selenium Ruby](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) or [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) which can execute the javascript.

> Using Ruby, is there a way to pass in the first duckduckgo page, but collect the final url that this redirects to?

In short, it would be quite difficult. You'd have to write quite a bit of custom code, and there are much better tools for this.

### What the browser is doing (the full story)

Here's the full story of what DuckDuckGo is doing with your requests:

#### Request #1

URL: `https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+goodreads+quotes+A+Promised+Land+Barack+Obama&t=h_&ia=web`. This returns a 301 redirect to: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+goodreads+quotes+A+Promised+Land+Barack+Obama&t=h_&ia=web`. Note that the 'www' is not in the returned URL.

#### Request #2

So we make a request to the new URL without the 'www':

```rb
redirected_url = res['location']
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(redirected_url))
```

If we were in the browser, we would be directed again to the goodreads site. However, if we inspect the response (i.e. `res`) they're not sending a true 301 redirect, duckduckgo is actually doing it with javascript. Here's the output of `res.body`:

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'><meta name='referrer' content='origin'><meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow'><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fwork%2Fquotes%2F86336100%2Da%2Dpromised%2Dland&rut=c5d81c30df243e291a04d906995e775c2f7c1bec359e8efa2ac0451aa701a8bf'></head><body><script language='JavaScript'>function ffredirect(){window.location.replace('/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fwork%2Fquotes%2F86336100%2Da%2Dpromised%2Dland&rut=c5d81c30df243e291a04d906995e775c2f7c1bec359e8efa2ac0451aa701a8bf');}setTimeout('ffredirect()',100);</script></body></html>
```

If you scroll through the text above, you'll notice a `<script>` tag with a `window.location.replace(...)`. This uses javascript to redirect our browser to another URL.

#### Request #3

Now, our browsers will follow the URL that's within that `window.location.replace` javascript call. However, that's tough to do with Ruby. It's likely DuckDuckGo implemented this as a security measure to prevent scraping, or as a way to track data. Either way, it would be tough to parse this from the javascript.

The result is that we are sent to a new page, something like: `https://duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fwork%2Fquotes%2F86336100%2Da%2Dpromised%2Dland&rut=c5d81c30df243e291a04d906995e775c2f7c1bec359e8efa2ac0451aa701a8bf`

#### Request #4

Finally, this last page is the one that redirects us to GoodReads, again through Javascript.

In short, check out [Selenium Ruby](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) or [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara). They have excellent documentation, and it should be able to support what you're trying to do! Good luck!