# Ruby net/http GET requests with empty body

Tags: python, ruby, openwebanalytics

I'm currently simply trying to get a simple GET request working in Ruby, however, I'm seeing some strange behavior.

I have an Open Web Analytics application running with Docker and it is reachable at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

I can reach the login site and everything works fine.

Now I want to do a GET request with Ruby to analyze the body of that request but I cannot get it to work, in other languages like Python or simple `GET` requests over the terminal it works fine. Why not with Ruby?

Here is my very basic Ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
uri = URI(url)

session = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = session.get(uri.request_uri)

puts response.body
```

Which doesn't output anything. If I look into the NGINX logs from the container, I can see the request being made but there is no further redirection as with the other methods (see below).

```
172.23.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2023:20:02:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Ruby" "-" 0.088 0.088 . -
```

If I do a simple GET over the terminal, it works:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

will output the correct body, and in the NGINX logs I can see the following:

```
172.23.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2023:20:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "lwp-request/6.61 libwww-perl/6.61" "-" 0.086 0.088 . -
172.23.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2023:20:20:10 +0000] "GET /index.php?owa_do=base.loginForm&owa_go=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2F& HTTP/1.1" 200 3200 "-" "lwp-request/6.61 libwww-perl/6.61" "-" 0.086 0.088 . -
```

Doing it in Python with the following basic code also works and gives similar results as with the terminal GET version:

```
import requests
x = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
print(x.content)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to [follow redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934185/ruby-net-http-following-redirects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with following redirects (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51072513/10529829)):

```
begin
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
  url = response['location']
end while response.is_a?(Net::HTTPRedirection)
```